# Full outer join issues when using group by

Tags: group-by, join

@@this may seem like a duplicate. The other post somehow posted as 'Guest' and will not allow me to make edits.@@

I have 4 subqueries and each of the subquery is grouped by 'Group name'. The attempt is to have each subquery as a column all grouped by the 'Group Name'. Here is the query:

```
select  coalesce(co.group_name, requests.group_Name, incidents.group_Name, problems.group_Name) as 'SD Groups'
, isnull(co.co, '') as 'CO'
, isnull(incidents.incidents, '' ) as 'Inc'
, isnull(problems.problems, '') as 'Prob'
, isnull(requests.requests, '') as 'Rqst'

from
(select 
    groups.last_name                        AS Group_Name   
    ,count(chg_ref_num)                         AS 'CO'
from chg
left join   ca_contact groups on chg.group_id = groups.contact_uuid 
left join   ca_contact assignee on chg.assignee = assignee.contact_uuid 
left join   ca_company cc on  assignee.company_uuid = cc.company_uuid                       
where   groups.last_name in ('8197 Qlikview Support', '8202 OBIEE-BIP'
                        , '8205 BI SAS', '8206 BI CCBI', '8208 BI ePlan Reporting and Support'
                        , '8211 BI Data Quality', '8212 BI EPM Report Architect/Developer'
                        , '8213 BI EPM Framework Architect/Developer', '8214 BI EPM User Experience'
                        , '8215 BI EPM OLAP Architect/Developer', '8219 BI Data Warehouse') 
and status = 'CL'
and     convert(varchar, dateadd(hh,-8,dateadd(ss,chg.close_date, '1970')), 101)  >= DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
and     parent is NULL  
and     cc.company_name = 'XYZ' 
group by    groups.last_name) as CO

full outer join 
(select                         
groups.last_name                        AS Group_Name   
    ,count(ref_num)                         AS Requests

from call_req cr                                
left join   ca_contact groups on cr.group_id = groups.contact_uuid  
left join   ca_contact assignee on cr.assignee = assignee.contact_uuid  
left join   ca_company cc on  assignee.company_uuid = cc.company_uuid                       
where   groups.last_name in ('8197 Qlikview Support', '8202 OBIEE-BIP'
                        , '8205 BI SAS', '8206 BI CCBI', '8208 BI ePlan Reporting and Support'
                        , '8211 BI Data Quality', '8212 BI EPM Report Architect/Developer'
                        , '8213 BI EPM Framework Architect/Developer', '8214 BI EPM User Experience'
                        , '8215 BI EPM OLAP Architect/Developer', '8219 BI Data Warehouse')                         
and     cr.status in ('CL')     
and     convert(varchar, dateadd(hh,-8,dateadd(ss,cr.close_date, '1970')), 101)  >= DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)                    
and     cr.parent is NULL   
and     cr.type = 'R'   
and     cc.company_name = 'XYZ'                 
group by    groups.last_name) as Requests
on co.group_name = requests.group_name

full outer join
(select                                 
groups.last_name                        AS Group_Name   
    ,count(ref_num)                     AS Problems

from call_req cr                                
left join   ca_contact groups on cr.group_id = groups.contact_uuid
left join   ca_contact assignee on cr.assignee = assignee.contact_uuid  
left join   ca_company cc on  assignee.company_uuid = cc.company_uuid                               
where   groups.last_name in ('8197 Qlikview Support', '8202 OBIEE-BIP'
                        , '8205 BI SAS', '8206 BI CCBI', '8208 BI ePlan Reporting and Support'
                        , '8211 BI Data Quality', '8212 BI EPM Report Architect/Developer'
                        , '8213 BI EPM Framework Architect/Developer', '8214 BI EPM User Experience'
                        , '8215 BI EPM OLAP Architect/Developer', '8219 BI Data Warehouse')                         
and     cr.status in ('CL')     
and     convert(varchar, dateadd(hh,-8,dateadd(ss,cr.close_date, '1970')), 101)  >= DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)                    
and     cr.parent is NULL   
and     cr.type = 'P'   
and     cc.company_name = 'XYZ'             
group by    groups.last_name) as Problems
on  requests.group_name = problems.group_name

full outer join 
(select                                 
groups.last_name                        AS Group_Name   
    ,count(ref_num)                         AS Incidents

from call_req cr                                
left join   ca_contact groups on cr.group_id = groups.contact_uuid  
left join   ca_contact assignee on cr.assignee = assignee.contact_uuid  
left join   ca_company cc on  assignee.company_uuid = cc.company_uuid                           
where   groups.last_name in ('8197 Qlikview Support', '8202 OBIEE-BIP'
                        , '8205 BI SAS', '8206 BI CCBI', '8208 BI ePlan Reporting and Support'
                        , '8211 BI Data Quality', '8212 BI EPM Report Architect/Developer'
                        , '8213 BI EPM Framework Architect/Developer', '8214 BI EPM User Experience'
                        , '8215 BI EPM OLAP Architect/Developer', '8219 BI Data Warehouse')                         
and     cr.status in ('CL')     
and     convert(varchar, dateadd(hh,-8,dateadd(ss,cr.close_date, '1970')), 101)  >= DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)                    
and     cr.parent is NULL   
and     cr.type = 'I'   
and     cc.company_name = 'XYZ'                 
group by    groups.last_name) as Incidents
on requests.group_name = incidents.group_name

order by 'SD Groups' asc
```

Here are the results:

```
Group_Name                                     CO  Inc Prob Rqst
8197 Qlikview Support                           0   1   0   7
8202 OBIEE-BIP                                  0   4   0   11
8205 BI SAS                                     0   11  1   11
8206 BI CCBI                                   10   17  0   43
8208 BI ePlan Reporting and Support             0   0   0   4
8211 BI Data Quality                            0   0   0   12
8212 BI EPM Report Architect/Developer          0   3   1   5
8214 BI EPM User Experience                     0   2   0   0
8214 BI EPM User Experience                     0   0   1   0
8215 BI EPM OLAP Architect/Developer            0   15  0   2
8219 BI Data Warehouse                         16   71  4   13
```

Notice two rows for Group 8214. Each group should be represented once and the desired result for Group 8214 should be:

```
Group_Name                                     CO  Inc Prob Rqst
8214 BI EPM User Experience                     0   2   1   0
```

What am I doing wrong? I think it has to do with the coalesce function. I tried other methods including

```
isnull(isnull(isnull(co.group_name, requests.group_Name), incidents.group_Name), problems.group_Name)
```

but with the same bad result.

Comment: Read [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for details about how to get the "guest" issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark based on the code you have posted, but I noticed your joins are inconsistent.

group by    groups.last_name) as Requests
on co.group_name = requests.group_name

group by    groups.last_name) as Problems
on  requests.group_name = problems.group_name

group by    groups.last_name) as Incidents
on requests.group_name = incidents.group_name

I think that it's creating a duplicate for 8214 because of the result set in one of the inline select statements, but I'd have to have access to the data to be sure.

As a minimum, I'd suggest that you format each 'JOIN ON' clause  with "co.group_name = new.group_name"

This may also be because of your full outer join which I'm not sure you need. I'm pretty sure Full Join will provide a line for every group which is encountered in each query and merge the results, however it's your work.